# How to upgrade the default TinyMCE editor on Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento-1.7

I'm using Magento 1.7.0.2 version and I need to upgrade it's default TinyMCE editor(version 3.4.7) to TinyMCE 4.0.12.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: 1) Why? 2) The TinyMCE integration in Magento is (IIRC) customized, as such, this question requires too broad of an answer.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to look into this. The reason I'm trying to upgrade the default editor is, my client wants to have the "Show block" feature which is available in TinyMCE 4.0.12 but not in version 3.4.7. I think the old CKEditor also has this feature but I couldn't find a plugin which is compatible with Magento 1.7.0.2

Comment: Great - I've reopened, but it's unlikely that you'll get much help here - I'm not aware of anyone attempting to do this. If you do accomplish this, may I suggest that you contribute the update to Magento, perhaps via pull request [here](https://github.com/magento/hackathon_january_2014)

Comment: Thanks benmarks. I'll do that if I come up with a solution.

Comment: for what its worth: I did manage to update TinyMCE in EE 1.1.2 to 4-0-3, but it was abandoned, as I found another solution to my project (and as mentioned by @Marius, the upgrade itself broke more 'things' than what it was worth the hassle ) http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6990/update-tiny-mce-to-latest-version-4-0-3-2013-08-08

Comment: Yep, "upgrading" anything such as frameworks, etc. usually breaks more than the features it adds. If it doesn't come stock with Magento, you only gain by going to the next version of Magento that has been marginally upgraded in those areas.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't upgrade tinymce. The editor comes with the Magento code and you can have troubles on any future upgrade.
Also Magento has some plugins for tinymce for adding widgets and config vars that might not work with the new version.

Comment: Thanks Marius for the answer. I'm new to Magento and wanted to check if there is any possibility.