# WYSIWYG Editor not working in IE 11

Tags: wysiwyg

I have been using magento 1.9.0.1 and when I click on the [image: WYSIWYG Editor] "Show/Hide Editor" button in CMS Pages it does nothing and showing up with blank white screen.

Please assist me to fix this issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Magento uses the TinyMCE WYSIWYG editor.
The problems for IE11 seem to be fixed in version 4.x:

http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=6307

On how to check to upgrade TinyMCE, check the following question and answers:

[Update tiny_mce to latest version 4.0.3 (2013-08-08)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6990/update-tiny-mce-to-latest-version-4-0-3-2013-08-08)